# How to save multi select lookup values

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lookup, multi-select

I have created a multi select lookup component.

[image]

Below I am pasting my code.
HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element" onmouseleave={toggleResult} data-source="lookupContainer">
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">{label}</label>
            <div class="lookupInputContainer slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                <!--------------- lookup field ----------------> <h1>
          <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Select Account">Select MSP Account</span>
        </h1>
                <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
                    <div class="searchBoxWrapper">
                        
                        <lightning-input type="search" data-id="userinput" name="searchText"
                            is-loading={isSearchLoading} value={searchKey} variant="label-hidden"
                            placeholder={placeholder} onchange={handleKeyChange} onclick={toggleResult} data-source="searchInputField"></lightning-input>
                           
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right"
                    role="none">
                    <template for:each={selectedRecords} for:item="serecord">
                        <span key={serecord.Id}>
                        <lightning-pill label={serecord.Name} name={serecord.Id} onremove={removeRecord}>
                                <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} variant="circle" alternative-text={serecord.Name}></lightning-icon>
                            </lightning-pill>
                        </span>
                    </template>
                </div>

                <div style="margin-top:0px" id="listbox-id-1"
                    class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                        <template for:each={searchRecords} for:item="obj">
                            <li key={obj.Id} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                                <div data-id={obj.Id} data-name={obj.Name} onclick={setSelectedRecord}
                                    class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta"
                                    role="option">
                                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                                        <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                                            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>  
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                                        <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{obj.Name}</span>
                                    <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">Account • {obj.Name}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </template>
                        <!-- if there is no records..-->
                        <template if:true={messageFlag}>
                            <li class="slds-listbox__item" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">No Records
                                Found...</li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                </div>
             
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>    <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" type="submit" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import retriveSearchData from '@salesforce/apex/reUsableMultiSelectLookupCtrl.retriveSearchData';

export default class DynmicMultiSelectPicklist extends LightningElement {
    @api objectname = 'Account';
    @api fieldnames = ' Id,Name';
    @api Label;
    @track searchRecords = [];
    @track selectedRecords = [];
    @api iconName = 'standard:account'
    @track messageFlag = false;
    @track isSearchLoading = false;
    @api placeholder = 'select account';
    @track searchKey;
    delayTimeout;

    searchField() {
        var selectedRecordIds = [];

        this.selectedRecords.forEach(ele=>{
            selectedRecordIds.push(ele.Id);
        })

        retriveSearchData({ ObjectName: this.objectname, fieldName: this.fieldnames, value: this.searchKey, selectedRecId: selectedRecordIds })
            .then(result => {
                this.searchRecords = result;
                this.isSearchLoading = false;
                const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer');
                const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;
                clsList.add('slds-is-open');

                if (this.searchKey.length > 0 && result.length == 0) {
                    this.messageFlag = true;
                } else {
                    this.messageFlag = false;
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    // update searchKey property on input field change  
    handleKeyChange(event) {
        // Do not update the reactive property as long as this function is
        this.isSearchLoading = true;
        window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
        const searchKey = event.target.value;
        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.searchKey = searchKey;
            this.searchField();
        }, 300);
    }

    // method to toggle lookup result section on UI 
    toggleResult(event) {
        const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer');
        const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;
        const whichEvent = event.target.getAttribute('data-source');

        switch (whichEvent) {
            case 'searchInputField':
                clsList.add('slds-is-open');
                this.searchField();
                break;
            case 'lookupContainer':
                clsList.remove('slds-is-open');
                break;
        }
    }

    setSelectedRecord(event) {
        var recId = event.target.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        let newsObject = this.searchRecords.find(data => data.Id === recId);
        this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
        this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer').classList.remove('slds-is-open');
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {
            each.value = '';
        });

        console.log(this.selectedRecords);
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: { selRecords }, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    removeRecord(event) {
        let selectRecId = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
            console.log('event.detail.name--------->' + event.detail.name);
            console.log('this.selectedRecords[i].Id--------->' + this.selectedRecords[i].Id);
            if (event.detail.name !== this.selectedRecords[i].Id)
                selectRecId.push(this.selectedRecords[i]);
        }

        this.selectedRecords = [...selectRecId];
        console.log('this.selectedRecords----------->' + this.selectedRecords);
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: { selRecords }, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
    handleSave(){
        this.selectedRecords
    }

}
```

Apex

```
public class reUsableMultiSelectLookupCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<sObject> retriveSearchData(String ObjectName, String fieldName, String value, List<String> selectedRecId) {
        List<sObject> sObjectResultList = new List<sObject>();
        if(selectedRecId == null)
            selectedRecId = new List<String>();

        if(String.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            String query = 'Select '+fieldName+' FROM '+ObjectName+' WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + value.trim() + '%\' and ID NOT IN: selectedRecId order by createdDate DESC LIMIT 5';
            for(sObject so : Database.Query(query)) {
                sObjectResultList.add(so);
            }
        }
        return sObjectResultList;
    }
}
```

I want to save the select accounts in the lead field called MSP Account. Please help.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The field in Lead (MSP Account), is it a lookup field or a text field or what's the type of the field?

Comment: The data type is Text Area, do I need to change the data type please do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to point directly to the account, then you should make a lookup field, but for lookup field you could only save one value (or in this case 1 account)
What do you want to save in the field? The selected accounts recordId? name? or any fields?

Comment: I want to save selected account name in the MSP Account. Just a question, the code above is it fine? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment.
I want to save the selected records accountId or accountName. Thanks!

Comment: The picture you provided above is your lightning web component right? You can add the logic when the save button is clicked, you can get all the selection's Id or Name or whatever field you want and then push it to the database

Comment: Although you've included the Controller code, it would be more useful to actually provide the LWC code as this is what you're asking about. Could please [edit] your question to include this?

Comment: @CallumMacErlich edit my question please check and let me know. Thanks in advance.